# In passbook(PHP-PKPass) implementation webServiceURL must be HTTPS or Can we use HTTP(Closed)

Tags: ios, web-services, passbook

i have typical problem while implementing passbook(PHP-PKPass) from Github. Device Registration is not working .i'm using HTTP Service(WebserviceURL) and Here is my code(Web service) :

```
<?php

   mysql_connect("localhost","username","Password");
        mysql_select_db("passesdb");

$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
    && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 'ApplePass') === 0 ){




    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);



    $device_id = $request[3];

    $pass_id = $request[5];

    $serial = $request[6];


 $phpObj = @file_get_contents('php://input');
 $f = json_encode($phpObj);

    // Catch the JSON post and decode it

    $dt = @file_get_contents('php://input');

    $device_token = json_decode($dt);

    $device_token1 = $device_token->pushToken;

  //  if (!$device_token) die('No Token Found'); // Token wasn't found



  $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);

 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO token(name)VALUES('".$dt."')");
    mysql_query($sql);

    exit;
}

?>
```

and my device log after pressing "add" button

```
Jun 23 15:47:15 vairats-iPhone passd[19548] <Warning>: Registering with Apple Push Service for push topics {(
        "pass.com.vaisoft.coupon"
    )}

Jun 23 15:47:15 vairats-iPhone locationd[54] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Jun 23 15:47:15 vairats-iPhone MobileSafari[19527] <Warning>: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <BrowserRootViewController: 0x1f5bf890> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

While deleting or Refreshing pass the Device log shows URL is firing but why is it not firing while Registering?

**Device log is as follows when Updating:**

```
Jun 23 15:51:37 vairats-iPhone locationd[54] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Jun 23 15:51:37 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Generating GET request with URL <http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/pits_demo/v1/passes/pass.com.vaisoft.coupon/test>
Jun 23 15:51:37 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Request contains header field <Authorization: ApplePass 72aa48d08db9a379f147e38fb23a3901>
Jun 23 15:51:38 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test, if-modified-since (null); with web service url webServiceURL) got response with code 404
Jun 23 15:51:38 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test, if-modified-since (null); with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404
Jun 23 15:51:38 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/pits_demo/v1/log>
Jun 23 15:51:38 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        logs =     (

            "[2014-06-21 14:34:17 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",
            "[2014-06-21 15:34:19 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",
            "[2014-06-23 15:50:24 +0530] Get pass task (pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test, if-modified-since (null); with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404",
            "[2014-06-23 15:50:35 +0530] Get pass task (pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test, if-modified-since (null); with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404"

        );
    }
```

**Device log is as follows when Deleting:**

```
Jun 23 15:55:27 vairats-iPhone locationd[54] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Jun 23 15:55:28 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Generating DELETE request with URL <http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/pits_demo/v1/devices/9516b180181695f4c9a5bb15a94ed270/registrations/pass.com.vaisoft.coupon/test>
Jun 23 15:55:28 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Request contains header field <Authorization: ApplePass 72aa48d08db9a379f147e38fb23a3901>
Jun 23 15:55:29 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Unregister task (for device 9516b180181695f4c9a5bb15a94ed270, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) got response with code 405
Jun 23 15:55:29 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Unregister task (for device 9516b180181695f4c9a5bb15a94ed270, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405
Jun 23 15:55:29 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/pits_demo/v1/log>
Jun 23 15:55:29 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        logs =     (
            "[2014-06-21 11:31:04 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 
            "[2014-06-21 11:44:13 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",
            "[2014-06-21 11:54:15 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",
            "[2014-06-21 12:04:16 +0530] Unregister task (for device d519e4750932a33023ef04cf2075c3f1, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",
pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test, if-modified-since (null); with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404",
            "[2014-06-23 15:52:31 +0530] Unregister task (for device ef4127d8aa3031223700ee2d163aca5d, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) encountered error: Unexpected response code 405",

        );
    }
Jun 23 15:55:29 vairats-iPhone passd[19568] <Warning>: Unregister task (for device 9516b180181695f4c9a5bb15a94ed270, pass type pass.com.vaisoft.coupon, serial number test; with web service url webServiceURL) will retry after 60 seconds
```

please help me.

Comment: This looks like your web server just isn't setup correctly. 404 and 405 mean that your route handling isn't correct. Have you implemented the Passkit WebService fully? Are you using a 3rd party library for your webservice?

Comment: please guide with any tutorial to setup server.Pass is downloaded and added to Database Successfully. Device is not register in Database.so,we didn't bother about DELETE or UPDATE.

Comment: Have you enabled the additional passbook logging under settings?

Comment: Yes enabled that too.

Comment: Can you repost your logs. The 3 lines you have posted after pressing the add button are insufficient to diagnose your registration problem.  Alternatively, can you post a url to your pass and we can check our own logs.

Comment: At final i came to know that my jailbroken phone is not registering details in Database and i tried same web service for other device it works. Thanks for support

Comment: @user2863321 i havind same issue showing   "encountered error: Unexpected response code 404" when im deleting can you help me ??